# How to count specified rows in another table

Tags: sql, node.js, knex.js

I am using Knex.js and want to count specific rows in the `bans` table. There is an `users` table, where two ip addresses are set. `current_ip` and `remote_ip`, where `current_ip` is also set in the `bans` table.

Now I want to first get the user by the `remote_ip` and then count the rows from `bans` with the `current_ip` from the selected user. It's important that `expiration` in `bans` is above the current timestamp.

I have already tried it with `LEFT JOIN`, which is kinda confusing to do in Knex.js.

```js
this.knex("bans").leftJoin(this.knex("users").where("remote_ip", ip)).where("expiration", ">", utils.getTime().count()
```

Let's say there is a row in `bans` with `current_ip` being `127.0.0.1` and `expiration` above the current timestamp, and in `users` the `current_ip` is `127.0.0.1` as well, `remote_ip` is `127.0.0.2`. Now I want to get the user by the `remote_ip` and use the `current_ip` given in the selected user to count the rows in `bans`.

I hope someone could help me, maybe even with building the query in Knex.

Answer (score 0):

I will step through the two pieces, and then there is a combined (one piece) solution at the bottom.

> Now I want to get the user by the remote_ip ...

It looks like you really want get the current_ip, but you can easily add the user to this too if you like. The SQL is:

```
 SELECT current_ip FROM users WHERE remote_ip = input_remote_ip
```

KNEX can be:

```
function getRemoteIpUsers(input_remote_ip) {
  return knex("users")
    .select("current_ip")
    .where("remote_ip", input_remote_ip)
} 
// returns array of user records
```

I would assume that in your users table, the user is unique, and your current_ip and remote_up can have the same values for multiple users, so the above query may return multiple rows, one for each user that has the inputted remote id.

Also, this query may return the same current_ip multiple times, one for each user. The combined query in the 'Finally' section below, ignores that by it's nature.

> ... and use the current_ip given in the selected user to count the rows in bans.

The SQL for this part is:

```
SELECT current_ip, count(*) as cnt FROM bans WHERE current_ip = input_current_ip AND expiration > get_time_count
```

The KNEX can be:

```
function countNonExpiredIpBans(input_current_ip) {
  return knex("bans")
    .count("* as cnt")
    .where("current_ip", input_current_ip)
    .andWhere("expiration", ">", utils.getTime().count() )
    .then((rec_arr) => {       // knex always returns an array of recs
       return { "current_ip": input_current_ip, 
                "cnt": rec_arr[0].cnt };  // I named the count field 'cnt'
    })
} 
// returns ip and count value;
```

---

**Finally,**

you can put the 2 functions together, but your single query attempt is probably the better way to go. So **shifting gears**, a combined SQL query would be:

```
SELECT current_ip, count(*) as cnt FROM bans 
  WHERE expiration > get_time_count
    AND current_ip IN (SELECT current_ip FROM users WHERE users.remote_ip = input_remote_ip)
  GROUP by current_ip
```

in KNEX this becomes...

```
function countCurrentIpBansForRemoteIp( input_remote_ip ) {
  return KNEX('bans')
    .select('current_ip')
    .count('* as cnt')
    .where("expiration", ">", utils.getTime().count())
    .whereIn('current_ip', function() {
         this.select('current_ip').from('users')
         .where("remote_ip", input_remote_ip);
    })
    .groupBy('current_ip')
}
// returns array of: { current_ip:'value', cnt: 88 }
```

Disclaimers - I don't have the actual data structures to run this, and I'm making some assumptions about your data structures, so hopefully I'm close, and this helps you.

Comment: The query seems to be working, but for some reason Knex doesn't return the count but the whole instance of it. That's how I am doing it:
```return this.knex("bans")
    .count("* as cnt")
    .where("expiration", ">", utils.getTime())
    .whereIn("ip_address", function() {
        this.select("current_ip").from("users").where("primary_ip", ip)
    })```

Comment: It is kind of irritating. Knex always returns an array, including when you do a count. The count should be inside the array.

Comment: Oh, perhaps you are referring to the fact that Knex (and the functions) return a promise, so you need a .then((rec_array) => { function stuff } ) to capture and process the array that is returned by the completed process?